# Is my macro a little bit too naughty?

Tags: c++, macros

I have made a macro. I am worried that it might be a little bit "too naughty", because *macros are evil*.

Here is the code without a macro:

```
case SDLK_a:
    _buffer_.InsertAtCursor('a');
    _buffer_.MutableCursor().Right();
    break;
```

And here is the macro definition and its usage:

```
#define SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(X, Y) \
{\
case X: \
    _buffer_.InsertAtCursor(Y); \
    _buffer_.MutableCursor().Right(); \
    break;\
}

SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_b, 'b');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_c, 'c');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_d, 'd');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_e, 'e');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_f, 'f');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_g, 'g');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_h, 'h');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_i, 'i');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_j, 'j');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_k, 'k');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_l, 'l');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_m, 'm');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_n, 'n');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_o, 'o');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_p, 'p');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_q, 'q');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_r, 'r');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_s, 's');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_t, 't');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_u, 'u');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_v, 'v');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_w, 'w');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_x, 'x');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_y, 'y');
SDLK_KEY_CASE_MACRO(SDLK_z, 'z');
```

Clearly this has saved me a lot of typing and a lot of lines of code. The code also compiles and runs ok.

- But is this macro too naughty? (Is it likely to produce unexpected behaviour, or is there a reason why I shouldn't use this "cheat" in my code?)

Comment: They are more evil in C++ than in C, so you should pick one.

Comment: "Clearly this has saved me a lot of typing and a lot of lines of code" - true, but was that code needed in the first place?

Comment: macros are as evil as the hammer that you use to drill a screw into your wall...

Comment: Can't you replace the whole `switch` with `_buffer_.InsertAtCursor(value - SDLK_b + 'b'); _buffer_.MutableCursor().Right();`? Speaking of which the `_buffer_.MutableCursor().Right();` part definitely doesn't need to be in the `switch`.

Comment: Couldn't you just replace this whole `switch` statement with a map?

Comment: @nwp That assumes the values of `SDLK_x` are sequential.

Comment: I would probably look to exploit a potential numeric relationship between SDLK_? and the `char` .

Comment: Write a function (or use a table/map) to translate `SDLK_...` into `...` and drop the switch. If that can't be done, I would prefer the "real" switch with all the lines over a macro

Comment: Why not a helper func with a request for inline? case SDLK_b: InsertAtCursor('b');

Comment: @Barmar: Also apply for `'a'`-`'z'`.

Comment: BTW, the `;` at the end of the macro invocation lines is adding an extra `;` to the code.

Comment: Using a map would probably be a better solution

Answer (score 3):

Like any sane system, `SDL_SCANCODE_A` (aka `SDLK_a`) is in a contiguous integer range and in order all the way to `SDL_SCANCODE_Z`.  The same is true of `'a'` through `'z'`.

```
if( val >= SDLK_a && val <= SDLK_z ) {
  _buffer_.InsertAtCursor( 'a' + (val-SDLK_a) );
  _buffer_.MutableCursor().Right();
} else {
  // handle other cases
}
```

this is more efficient, shorter and clearer than a wall of macros.

You may have to repeat for digits.

For special characters (tab, quotes, etc) I wouldn't rely on things being nicely arraged.  There you'll want to have a short table

```
struct SDL_table {
  unsigned code; 
  char value;
};

SDL_table table[] = {
  {SDL_SCANCODE_TAB, '\t'},
  // ... etc
};
```

then, after the earlier checks have failed, do a quick search through that table

```
auto it = std::find_if( std::begin(table), std::end(table), [&](SDL_table t) { return t.code == val; } );
if (it != std::end(table)) {
  _buffer_.InsertAtCursor( it->value );
  _buffer_.MutableCursor();
} else {
  // deal with unrecognized scancode
}
```

I'd probably refactor the `_buffer_` code out at this point.

```
char SDLK_to_char( unsigned sdlk ) {
  if( sdlk >= SDLK_a && sdlk <= SDLK_z )
     return 'a' + (val-SDLK_a);
  if( sdlk >= SDLK_0 && sdlk <= SDLK_9 )
     return '0' + (sdlk-SDLK_0);
  struct SDLK_entry {
    unsigned code; 
    char value;
  };

  static const SDLK_entry table[] = {
    {SDL_SCANCODE_TAB, '\t'},
    // ... etc
  };

  auto it = std::find_if( std::begin(table), std::end(table),
   [&](auto&& t) { return t.code == sdlk; }
  );
  if (it != std::end(table))
    return it->value;
  return 0; // null for failure
}
```

then

```
char c = SDLK_to_char( sdlk );

if (c) {
  _buffer_.InsertAtCursor( c );
  _buffer_.MutableCursor().Right();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would avoid the macro - even if I had to write the complete `switch` with the cases.

But first I would consider an alternative approach.

For instance a look-up table to translate `SDLK_...` into `...`. In C++ you could base that on `std::map`

Like:

```
  std::map<SDLK_type, char> look_up_table = {{SDLK_a, 'a'}, {SDLK_b, 'b'}};

  auto i = look_up_table.find(SDLK_value);
  if (i != look_up_table.end())
  {
    char c = i->second;
    _buffer_.InsertAtCursor(c);
    _buffer_.MutableCursor().Right();
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: The initialization of table ends up ... wanting to have a macro in it.

Comment: The table should be initialized with an initializer, not a function.

Comment: `std::map<SDLK_TYPE, char>` would reduce complexity.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Agree.